# Metal Device (MTLDevice) variable becomes nil after initialization

Tags: ios, swift, macos, metal

I have a renderer class in my Metal Swift (iOS/MacOS) project that is an MTKViewDelegate. I extract the MTLDevice using MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(), however after init, it becomes nil? I wonder if I've missed a quirk of Swift or Metal here. This is roughly how the code goes,

```
class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    var device: MTLDevice!
​
    init(metalView: MTKView) {
        guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else
        {
            fatalError("GPU not available")
        }
​        metalView.device = device
        if device != nil {
            print (“device not nil”)
        }
    }
​
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        if device == nil {
            print (“device is nil here”)
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewController I do

```
guard let metalView = view as? MTKView else {
   fatalError("Metal View not setup")
}
renderer = Renderer(metalView: metalView)
```

What I see happen is:

```
device not nil
device is nil here
device is nil here
device is nil here
device is nil here
```

at 60hz on every draw call

EDIT: Edited code to make it clear that the device actually is being assigned to a variable in the global scope (metalView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code you are not assigning local device to implicitly unwrapped global device variable. Assign local device to global one to fix the issue.

```
guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else
        {
            fatalError("GPU not available")
        }
self.device = device
```

Comment: Sorry, I do, do that. I just edited that line out to make it concise (I've put it back in). Note how the device is saved as part of the metalview variable. I'm hoping that's enough of a global scope variable to keep the variable alive?

Comment: From what I can see you are assigning device variable to MTKView instance. But draw func is called on render right?. If so you are trying to access different device instance.

Comment: @pj_mukh Please check the above comment.

Comment: Got it! That was the fix, I figured referring to 'device' is the same as 'self.device'. I was incorrect.